# How do I serialize to Json with Jersey? (I'm using Gradle)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, gradle, jersey

I'm trying to get Jersey to serialize my objects whenever I return them, like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/new")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User newUser(String username) {
    return new User(username);
}
```

When I do a POST request to this with for example "john", It should respond with a json representation of a `User`. However, all it does is give a error status 500, and the server logs the following

> Global Reader Interceptors:
>      org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor
>       Global Writer Interceptors:
>      org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor
>      org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor
>   name: carl
>   returning: cd.orbit.server.User@4c84f510
>   jul 05, 2014 10:17:49 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
>   SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class cd.orbit.server.User, genericType=class cd.orbit.server.User.

Which makes me think that somehow there's no library/method found to turn my User object into Json, however I have the following gradle build file (notice the jackson dependencies):

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.6'
}
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.6'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'

compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.10.1'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.10.1'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.10.1'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.10'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.3.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.3.2'

compile 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:1.0.0'

}

appengine {
httpPort = 8085

appcfg {
    email = 'aaaaa'
    passIn = true

    app {
        id = 'aaaaa'
    }
}
}

task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
from configurations.runtime
into "${rootDir}/war/WEB-INF/lib"
}
```

Btw the `User` class uses all the correct annotations.

Why doesn't my server (Google App Engine) running Jersey not return items in JSON format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the dependency to a concrete JSON provider for Jersey. To use Jackson as your JSON provider you need to add jersey-media-json-jackson module.

Then you need to register `JacksonFeature` as follows.

```
final Application application = new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("your.packages.to.scan")
    .register(JacksonFeature.class)
    // rest omitted
```

Check that you have all other dependencies required by jersey-media-jackson module [here](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.10.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-json-jackson/dependencies.html).

Finally, you can find more details [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json).

Comment: I already have the JSON provider dependencies (see my post). I now tried to register the JacksonFeature, as you've shown above. I put the code in my newUser() method and changed the package to mine. It however didn't solve my problem, nothing has changed. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I can not see `jersey-media-json-jackson` in your dependency list. The `application` has to be registered in your web application `web.xml` deployment descriptor. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet) for details provided that you use Servlet-based environment.

Comment: Aaah I see, I googled that specific dependency and added it. I was only looking at https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.10.1/jersey/project/jersey-media-moxy/dependencies.html and added all the dependencies in the first dependencies section. Since that's not all I have to do, how can I know which dependencies I DO have to add (in general)? In other words, how did you know that That dependency had to be added? Thanks!

Comment: Usually the required dependencies are listed in a project documentation. In case of Jersey, you can find all available modules [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html#modules). Anyway, if the answer helped you to solve your issue, mark it as accepted so that others can reuse the solution.